# How to run path setting script in vscode terminal at startup?

Tags: visual-studio-code, terminal, command-prompt

I have a script which sets path variables. I have to run this script manually every time I start a new terminal instance.

I am looking for an automated way to run this script at startup for every terminal instance.

I have tried the below approach which doesn't work

```
{
  "terminal.integrated.profiles.windows": {
    "Command Prompt": {
      "path": "cmd.exe",
      "args": [
         "-noexit",
         "-file",
         "h:\\all-languages-env.cmd"
      ]
    }
  },
  "terminal.integrated.defaultProfile.windows": "Command Prompt",
}
```

I am expecting the script `h:\all-languages-env.cmd` to run at every terminal(Command Prompt) startup.

The script file is as below

```
@ECHO OFF
call devtools isSupported nodejs 16.13.0 || exit /B %ERRORLEVEL%
call devtools isSupported phantomjs 2.1.1 || exit /B %ERRORLEVEL%
set npm_config_registry=http://example.com
set npm_config_user_agent="npm/{npm-version} node/{node-version} {platform} {arch} | NDS %USERNAME% %COMPUTERNAME%"
set SASS_BINARY_SITE=http://example.com/node-sass
set SPAWN_WRAP_SHIM_ROOT=H:\.nodejs
set CHROME_BIN="C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe"
set npm_config_prefix=H:\.nodejs\npm\8
set npm_config_cache=H:\.nodejs\npm\8\cache
set npm_config_tmp=H:\.nodejs\npm\8\tmp
set NODEJS_16_13_0=H:\nodejs\16
set PATH=%NODEJS_16_13_0%;H:\.nodejs\npm\8;%PATH%
type nul > H:\nodejs\16\lastUsed
set PHANTOMJS_2_1_1=H:\phantomjs\2\bin
set PHANTOMJS_BIN=%PHANTOMJS_2_1_1%\phantomjs.exe
set PATH=%PHANTOMJS_2_1_1%;%PATH%
type nul > H:\phantomjs\2\lastUsed
ECHO javascript environment set
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`cmd.exe` uses different arguments

```
{
  "terminal.integrated.profiles.windows": {
    "Command Prompt": {
      "path": "cmd.exe",
      "args": [
         "/K",
         "h:\\all-languages-env.cmd"
      ]
    }
  },
  "terminal.integrated.defaultProfile.windows": "Command Prompt",
}
```

Comment: however this does not help when I try to debug tests with the vscode run and debug extension as the extension does not wait for the script passed in args to complete execution...do you know any workaround for this?

Comment: @RahulYadav what is the `vscode run and debug extension`

Comment: there's an option in vscode called `Run and Debug (Ctrl + Shift + D)` besides Explorer, Search and Source Control

Comment: @RahulYadav Have you tried different values of the `console` property of the launch config

Comment: value for `console` is `integratedTerminal`